# Show currently active try-catch blocks in Xdebug

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug

I just thought debugging nested try-catch blocks can be pretty difficult especially if they are spread around in a framework as well as in your own code.

I don't want to talk about the fact if this is actually a good software pattern or not, just the fact that it sometimes is unavoidable and therefore people have to deal with it.

So is there maybe currently a way how to debug that in Xdebug?
If not - could this be a useful feature which Xdebug could maybe support?

Comment: That sounds more like a feature of a development environment... the debugger doesn't know which handler will catch an exception _before_ it happens. The runtime engine might know, but PHP doesn't expose that information afaik. Exceptions bubble up until caught, with PHP as last instance, which you'll see as unhandled exception in the error log. However, you can try the Stack Trace feature of xdebug, although it's nothing else than the debug_stacktrace() contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the best that Xdebug could do is to mark a stack frame in the stack traces as an "in try...catch" block. Although you'll have to ask for that as a feature at https://bugs.xdebug.org .

If you just want to break on any exception happening, then you can set a breakpoint on the `*` Exception, which at least the VS Code Adapter and  PhpStorm support.